Why in GODOT and most game engine, Y axes is inverted?
The inverted Y-axis in Godot (and many other game engines) might seem counterintuitive. Why is it typically set up this way, and why is there limited information available on this topic online?
Someone could explain me? Thank you

Related:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83570/why-is-the-origin-in-computer-graphics-coordinates-at-the-top-left

Per the Transforms tutorial:

Following the OpenGL convention, X is the Right axis, Y is the Up axis and Z is the Forward axis.

As for why OpenGL uses Y = Up, if you ask a dozen people you'll get 13 answers. The most convincing argument I've heard is that, since the Y axis is used for Up in 2D (at least, it is in OpenGL), it makes sense for it to be Up in 3D as well. But ultimately, I think the real reason that Y is up in OpenGL is simply that it's the convention at this point, so everyone just needs to do it.
I definitely still need to remind myself that Y is Up instead of Z almost every time I'm in Godot, so you're not alone.
